# Files specified in MANIFEST.in ignored when creating a python package

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, python-packaging

Maybe I'm already too tired (it's already late) but I'm not able to find out why files specified in `MANIFEST.in` are being ignored, even though `include_package_data = True` is set.

Here's my training setup:

```
.
├── config
│  └── conf.yaml
├── MANIFEST.in
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── superapp
   ├── __init__.py
   └── main.py
```

setup.cfg:

```
[metadata]
name = superapp
version = 0.1.3
description = My superdupermega app
classifiers = 
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3


[options]
zip_safe = False
include_package_data=True
packages = find:
install_requires = 
    loguru
    pyyaml

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts = 
    gaga = superapp.main:main
```

MANIFEST.in

```
graft config
```

pyproject.toml

```
[build-system]
requires = ['setuptools>=58.3.0']
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

Yep, I know that this might be a classic, but I'm really out of ideas. I know that there's still the option to use `package_data` as well, but shouldn't `include_package_data` do the trick?
Neither `python setup.py sdist` nor `python setup.py bdist_wheel` included `config`.

Comment: Setup seems correct. Maybe the changes are not taken into account for some reason. I would recommend removing all build artifacts (`*.egg-info/`, `build/`, `dist/`, etc.) then try again. -- Then carefully check the console output for some clues, and look into the the build artifacts (look into `*.egg-info/SOURCES.txt` and again in the sdist and wheel archives). -- This is what I use as reference (although it might be outdated now, not sure): https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/package_data.html

Comment: I tried it once again and I see that this file is included when executing `python setup.py sdist`. However, when I install it to another venv with `pip install superapp.<version>.tar.gz` it builds a wheel and installs it. After that `config/conf.yaml` cannot be found in that virtual environment, it is lost. But why?

Comment: I guess it is because `config` is not added to `packages`. Since the project does not seem to contain a `config/__init__.py`, I assume that `find_packages` (or here `packages = find:`) does not consider the `config` directory as a Python importable package. So 2 things: ***1.*** add a `config/__init__.py` file (even if totally empty) ***2.*** I would even recommend placing `config` as a sub-directory of `superapp`, so that there would be: `superapp/config/conf.yaml`.

Comment: I already did as described in #2, the file (and directory) was finally there. However, it's really strange that you can add something from outside a package, but it's not processed when installing the package. Perhaps it is to preserve a somehow clean structure under `site-packages`. Any, thanks for sharing your attention and knowledge with me.

Comment: "_it's really strange that you can add something from outside a package, but it's not processed when installing the package_" ... this can be useful: typically what I do is that I add the tests in all my sdists, but I do not want the tests to get installed so I do not add the tests to the wheels ... this can also be used for source code that needs to be compiled, uncompiled source code in the sdists on one hand and on the other hand compiled binaries in the wheels that then get installed.